# Selenium webdriver execution stops after abruptly

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My scenario is:

```
1. Click on new user button
2. Input the username and other details
3. Click on the save button
4. Click on logout button using JavascriptExecutor.
```

Automated the above scenario with Selenium Webdriver.
During execution somehow the username was not inputted (Doesn't matter. Some data issue). After that I clicked on save button which prompts a browser alert which says user details not saved.
Now I use javascriptexecutor to click the logout button while alert is active. After that, execution becomes not responsive for about 2-3 hours and then it throws an error.

> WebDriverException: Error communicating with the remote browser.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Have you tried doing the same after dismissing the alert?
I guess, alert would be a windows dialog box, and makes entire browser inaccessible once active. So executing a JavaScript on an inaccessible browser may have resulted in browser being unresponsive.

Comment: Hi please do as said by @  Varun Bajpai if problem persists then comment

Comment: Thanks Varun. Problem was with the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Posting comment as answer so that it would benefit others

Have you tried doing the same after dismissing the alert?

Alert would be a windows dialog box, and makes entire browser inaccessible once active. So executing a JavaScript on an inaccessible browser may have resulted in browser being unresponsive